# Breadth first search and lifetimes

Tags: algorithm, rust

I want to write a function that uses breadth-first search on a binary tree to print node values in order:

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::ops::Deref;

struct BinarySearchNode<'a> {
    value: &'a str,
    key: i32,
    left: Option<Box<BinarySearchNode<'a>>>,
    right: Option<Box<BinarySearchNode<'a>>>,
}

impl<'a> BinarySearchNode<'a> {
    pub fn print(&self) -> String {
        let mut queue = VecDeque::new();
        let mut output = String::new();
        queue.push_back(&self);

        while let Some(ref current) = queue.pop_front() {
            if let Some(left_node) = current.left {
                queue.push_back(&left_node.deref());
            }
            if let Some(right_node) = current.right {
                queue.push_back(&right_node.deref());
            }

            output = output + current.value + "\n";
        }

        output
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

I get the error

```
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:19:34
   |
19 |                 queue.push_back(&left_node.deref());
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ does not live long enough
   |
note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 13:40...
  --> src/main.rs:13:41
   |
13 |         let mut queue = VecDeque::new();
   |                                         ^
note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the statement at 19:16
  --> src/main.rs:19:17
   |
19 |                 queue.push_back(&left_node.deref());
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
  --> src/main.rs:19:17
   |
19 |                 queue.push_back(&left_node.deref());
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: `left_node` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:19:34
   |
19 |                 queue.push_back(&left_node.deref());
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 13:40...
  --> src/main.rs:13:41
   |
13 |         let mut queue = VecDeque::new();
   |                                         ^
note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the if let at 18:12
  --> src/main.rs:18:13
   |
18 |             if let Some(left_node) = current.left {
   |             ^

error: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:22:34
   |
22 |                 queue.push_back(&right_node.deref());
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ does not live long enough
   |
note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 13:40...
  --> src/main.rs:13:41
   |
13 |         let mut queue = VecDeque::new();
   |                                         ^
note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the statement at 22:16
  --> src/main.rs:22:17
   |
22 |                 queue.push_back(&right_node.deref());
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
  --> src/main.rs:22:17
   |
22 |                 queue.push_back(&right_node.deref());
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: `right_node` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:22:34
   |
22 |                 queue.push_back(&right_node.deref());
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 13:40...
  --> src/main.rs:13:41
   |
13 |         let mut queue = VecDeque::new();
   |                                         ^
note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the if let at 21:12
  --> src/main.rs:21:13
   |
21 |             if let Some(right_node) = current.right {
   |             ^

error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:18:38
   |
18 |             if let Some(left_node) = current.left {
   |                         ---------    ^^^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
   |                         |
   |                         hint: to prevent move, use `ref left_node` or `ref mut left_node`

error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:21:39
   |
21 |             if let Some(right_node) = current.right {
   |                         ----------    ^^^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
   |                         |
   |                         hint: to prevent move, use `ref right_node` or `ref mut right_node`
```

I needed to `deref()` because simply using the operator `*` was causing a type mismatch as it expected a reference and not a box. It seems those dereference slightly differently and at least in stable I can't destructure it either.

I get that this value is scoped within the `while` loop and doesn't live long enough to be in the `VecDeque` (if this is the right data structure for the job) but I'm not sure what the best way to go about extending that lifetime is or if there's simply a better way to write this entire thing as it feels a bit complex.

My main problem is that I'm not sure where to start refactoring this code and I surprisingly had a hard time finding examples of a breadth-first search performed on a binary tree in Rust to take patterns from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem lies in this line (and the `right` version):

```
if let Some(left_node) = current.left
```

This tries to *move* the value contained in `current.left` into the pattern on the right side. the problem is that `current.left` is an `Option<Box<BinarySearchNode<'a>>>`. When you move the `Box` out of `current`, that would leave `current` without a valid value for `left`! Accessing that value in the future would lead to bad behavior.

Instead, you need to leave the value where it is and instead take a reference. The two main ways are to use the `ref` pattern modifier:

```
if let Some(ref left_node) = current.left
```

Or to call [`as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref):

```
if let Some(left_node) = current.left.as_ref()
```

Here is complete code:

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

struct BinarySearchNode<'a> {
    value: &'a str,
    key: i32,
    left: Option<Box<BinarySearchNode<'a>>>,
    right: Option<Box<BinarySearchNode<'a>>>,
}

impl<'a> BinarySearchNode<'a> {
    pub fn print(&self) -> String {
        let mut queue = VecDeque::new();
        let mut output = String::new();
        queue.push_back(self);

        while let Some(current) = queue.pop_front() {
            if let Some(left_node) = current.left.as_ref() {
                queue.push_back(left_node);
            }
            if let Some(right_node) = current.right.as_ref() {
                queue.push_back(right_node);
            }

            output = output + current.value + "\n";
        }

        output
    }
}

fn main() {
    let root = BinarySearchNode {
        value: "a",
        key: 0,
        left: Some(Box::new(BinarySearchNode {
            value: "b",
            key: 1,
            left: None,
            right: None,
        })),
        right: Some(Box::new(BinarySearchNode {
            value: "c",
            key: 2,
            left: None,
            right: None,
        })),
    };
    println!("{}", root.print());
}
```

Comment: Huh, that wasn't apparent but it makes sense to me now.  I thought my reference wasn't living long enough.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
pub fn print(&self) -> String {
    let mut queue = VecDeque::new();
    let mut output = String::new();

    if let Some(ref left_node) = self.left {
        queue.push_back(left_node);
    }
    if let Some(ref right_node) = self.right {
        queue.push_back(right_node);
    }

    while let Some(ref current) = queue.pop_front() {
        if let Some(ref left_node) = current.left {
            queue.push_back(left_node);
        }
        if let Some(ref right_node) = current.right {
            queue.push_back(right_node);
        }

        output = output + current.value + "\n";
    }

    output
}
```

Comment: Your answer would be more useful with some text that highlights and explains the differences between this code and OPs. Otherwise people will find it difficult to apply the changes that you have made to their own code experiencing the same problem.

Comment: This code also does not print out the value of the starting node (`self`); it only prints out the children.